# Get selected index from gridview with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

All i want is to get the selected index (or selectedvalue or selectedDataKey) of a gridview with jquery so i can use jquery ajax to load its data with that ID as parameter.

How can i get it with jquery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want that?

---

Here is an idea.

Set `SelectedRowStyle="myselection"`.
Now place a label in GridView in any existing TemplateField.
(Dont create any new `asp:TemplateField` because it will add a new column)

```
<asp:Label ID="HiddenLabel" runat="server" 
        CssClass="myindex"
        Text='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'
        style="display:none;"/>
```

Now retrieve the selected row index like this.

```
var selectedIndex = -1;
if($(".myselection").length){
    selectedIndex  = $(".myselection .myindex").html() - 0;
}
```

Update:

Multiple GridViews? You could still do that. Give each GridView a separate CssClass. `CssClass="grid1"`

```
var selectedIndex = -1;
if($(".grid1 .myselection").length){
    selectedIndex  = $(".grid1 .myselection .myindex").html() - 0;
}
```

I do not know of any simpler way. Sorry.

Comment: i was hoping i can get a more straighforward way to do this. i have several gridviews in one page so the class aproach will have to change in order for this to work. I have something like this in mind in case there's no other workaround for this issue! thanks naveen